# Merge large number of files and removing them of the fly

Tags: bash, out-of-memory

I am trying to concatenate a large number of files (~20k) on different directories into a single big one.

The issue is the global size of the files is around 40G and I don't have enough space on the drive to store a second 40G file. I plan to run a simple script which will cat and rm files to empty space.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

for file in library/*/*
do
    echo $file
    cat $file >> teeest
    rm $file
done
```

I tried it on a small test sample and it seems to works fine. However I'm a bit concerned about `>>` and memory usage.

Since I will remove a concatenated file instantly I want to be sure it wont crash midway because it runs out of memory, because I made a mistake in the script or something I haven't thought about.

The machine I'm working on have 64GB of RAM and 16 cores.
Thank for your help :)

Comment: Even if it get crash content of the last file will be stored in the large file. Why don't you use zip utility and zip all the files to one zip file.

Comment: you can use also a 1-line-script ```find . -follow -type f -exec cat {} \; >> test ``` this is without the remove command but you can concatenate 2 or more command.

Comment: I have a 2 core 8GB box and I created 20k files 1MB each and then did your script on them and I didn't see the RAM utilization move one bit...

Comment: When you open a file in append mode, it doesn't need to access the existing contents at all, or make a copy, if that was the memory usage you were concerned about. I just extends the file on disk and writes to it. As others have said, you could gzip the new data as you append it, to get some compression. gzip has fairly modest memory requirements that are generally fixed at the default setting.

Comment: Sweet, I was afraid `>>` would keep the file open for some reason, I've run it and it seems to go well for now, thanks guys :)

@TomasHrubovcak how did you created those files ? I could use a line to create size-specific files automatically. I usually create a file manually and copy-paste some dummy text inside until it get the size I want and then I copy those

Comment: `for i in $(seq 1 20000); do touch $i; dd if=/dev/urandom of=$i bs=1024 count=1024 >/dev/null 2>&1; done`
EDIT: you can set the size to exactly what you need with multiplying bit size (`bs`) by `count` of the bits in the `dd` command. My command gives you exactly 1MB

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you very much !